# CSS transition not working in Safari (first-shot)

Tags: jquery, css, safari, transition

Absolute noob here, so apologies go in advance.

I've made a start/stop slowdown based on previous examples I've seen here.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vlory73/oq1samnz/)

```
.small-wheel, .big-wheel{
  transition: all 2s ease-out; 
}
```

The problem is that Safari is exhibiting an immediate stop (on the first command) without the transition taking effect. After this first time, the transition works every time fine.

On Firefox and Chrome, no such behaviour.

I would greatly appreciate your help on this one.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that using

```
.stop {
   -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
   -o-animation-play-state: paused;
   -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
   animation-play-state: paused;  
}
```

is not very cross-browser compatible, especially on iOS browsers.

instead I am now using:

```
.stop{
   -webkit-animation: none !important;
   -moz-animation:none !important;
   animation:none !important; 
}
```